Getting TypeError when trying to build and running IOS simulator using Cordova
I am creating a ionic app for cross-platform.
Getting this Error while creating build and running IOS simulator using Cordova
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('EACCES')
    at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:123:9)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:32:22

I haven't find any solution for this to try.
But I am expecting simulator will run.

You already checked posts like: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/issues/850
